# How to convert a dataframe into a 2D array in-order to run some calculations?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
             timestamp     close
.. .......... ........  ........
86 2017-03-12 14:00:00  0.000077
87 2017-03-12 16:00:00  0.000076
88 2017-03-12 18:00:00  0.000074
89 2017-03-12 20:00:00  0.000073
90 2017-03-12 22:00:00  0.000077
.. .......... ........  ........
```

I have prototyped some `tangent` and `curvature` calculations that work with the following data:

```
np.array([[0.0, 0.0], [0.13216, 0.11837], [0.25379, 0.05027], ... ])
```

How can I construct a numpy array from the data frame as a 2D data, just like the array above? I guess, the `close` data will be the `Y` axis, and the dates will be the `X` data, maybe something like this: `0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 ...` as they are equally spaced date-time objects? So, probably something like this:

```
np.array([[0.0, 0.000077], [0.1, 0.000076], [0.2, 0.05027], [0.3, 0.000074], ... ])
```

Then once I do the calculation, which will yield a float number, I will need to add it back into the pandas data-frame and make sure it lines-up with the timestamp.

```
             timestamp     close change
.. .......... ........  ........ ......
86 2017-03-12 14:00:00  0.000077 0.00345
87 2017-03-12 16:00:00  0.000076 0.64477
88 2017-03-12 18:00:00  0.000074 0.32356
89 2017-03-12 20:00:00  0.000073 0.13331
90 2017-03-12 22:00:00  0.000077 0.66436
.. .......... ........  ........ .......
```

I probably will be able to do that by dissecting the dataframe, run some for loops to construct the array and do the same in reverse to inject the new column into the pandas dataframe. However, I am interested to learn if there is an elegant way for doing this.

*--- (CLARIFICATION) ---*

So I am not after the actual calculations. I already know how to perform those. But my function expects a **2D** array as in **X**, **Y** values. So I need to convert the `date` column into **X** values and then store the `close` column as the **Y** value. So that I can run it through my calculation. Then the output will be an array of float numbers. I will need to inject everyone of those floats into a new column inside my pandas dataframe. And when doing that, I will need to make sure that each value matches the correct date row.

Comment: unclear what you want. You have a function but we shall guess how to apply it? could you provide some context on curvature and tangent of what?

Comment: That is not part of the question. It is a calculation that is doing what I need it to be doing. The question is more about how to organise the `close` and `date` columns of a pandas dataframe into a 2D `[X, Y]` numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much just need the `df.values` attribute, although you need to deal with the times first:

```
# Make a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(timestamp=['2017-03-12 14:00:00', '2017-03-12 16:00:00', '2017-03-12 18:00:00', '2017-03-12 20:00:00', '2017-03-12 22:00:00'], close=[0.000077, 0.000076, 0.000074, 0.000073, 0.000077]))
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

# Convert timestamp to floats
df['time_as_float'] = df.timestamp.values.astype(float)

# Make input numpy array
values = df[['time_as_float', 'close']].values

# Run through your function
solution = your_function_name(values)

# Save to array
df['solution'] = solution
```

If you really want the times to be 0.1, 0.2, etc you can just further transform the `time_as_float` column.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test this in a bit.

Comment: If you know for a fact that timesteps will always be evenly-spaced, you can just use the dataframe index like @Piinthesky suggests. That is probably simpler. This version will work for uneven sampling as well though, so is slightly more general.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you don't actually need a specific spacing for the X column of your numpy array. If not, you can omit the division step.

```
import pandas

#convert the panda column into a 2D numpy array with index and "close" column
nparr = df["close"].reset_index().values 

nparr[:, 0] /= 10      #only, if you really need a 0.1 spacing for this column
print(nparr.dtype)     #is float64 array

#do some calculations for column "change"

df["change"] = nparr[:,0]    #append column that contains "change" values
```

In this example, I assumed that you reuse column 0 of the numpy array to store your calculated "change" values. The reason for this is, that if you append a new column to a numpy array, numpy copies the whole array. So if you really want to keep column 0 of your numpy array for whatever reason, I would rather define a numpy array in the initial step with three columns.